# undefined reference to `calloc' when linking with arm-none-eabi-ld

Tags: c, gcc, arm

I'm encountering an error that is doubtless due to some limit of my knowledge on how linkers work. Some ANSI C code I've written that compiles and links perfectly well on my OS X box fails to link with `arm-none-eabi-ld` when cross-compiled for ARM.

Here's the result from a clean `make` (with `--verbose` on `ld`):

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -o build/fft.o src/fft.c -g -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MD -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -DPART_TM4C123GH6PM -c -I../tivaware -DTARGET_IS_BLIZZARD_RA1
arm-none-eabi-gcc -o build/main.o src/main.c -g -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MD -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -DPART_TM4C123GH6PM -c -I../tivaware -DTARGET_IS_BLIZZARD_RA1
arm-none-eabi-ld -o build/a.out build/fft.o build/main.o --verbose -T TM4C123GH6PM.ld --entry main --gc-sections
GNU ld (32-bit ARM EABI Toolchain JBS-FLOAT_IO-SGXXLITE_ML-2014.05-28-v2013.05-36-g3f93944) 2.24.51.20140217
  Supported emulations:
   armelf
opened script file TM4C123GH6PM.ld
using external linker script:
==================================================
MEMORY
{
    FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x00040000
    SRAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0X00008000
}

SECTIONS
{
    /* code */
    .text :
    {
        _text = .;
        /* ensure ISR vectors are not removed by linker */
        KEEP(*(.isr_vector))
        *(.text*)
        *(.rodata*)
        _etext = .;
    } > FLASH

    /* static data */
    .data : AT(ADDR(.text) + SIZEOF(.text))
    {
        _data = .;
        *(vtable)
        *(.data*)
        _edata = .;
    } > SRAM

    /* static uninitialized data */
    .bss :
    {
        _bss = .;
        *(.bss*)
        *(COMMON)
        _ebss = .;
    } > SRAM

}

==================================================
attempt to open build/fft.o succeeded
build/fft.o
attempt to open build/main.o succeeded
build/main.o
build/fft.o: In function `dft':
/path/src/fft.c:97: undefined reference to `calloc'
```

There's a number of other undefined symbols (`__aeabi_dadd`, `__muldc3`), which I've truncated for brevity.

Comment: I don't see `libc.lib` or `glibc.lib` linked.  `calloc`, `muldc3`, etc. are in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microcontrollers usually (practical reasons) are not configured with dynamic memory allocation facility.
so, malloc, calloc, free will not be available.

Recommendation: use static array to allocate memory.

even after reading this you need dynamic memory allocation, you can use [newlibc](https://sourceware.org/newlib/)
but beware that in case your heap and stack overlap, you will be in problem.